# Python vba excel reference

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I seem to be falling at the first hurdle and I have no idea why. My code:

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

xl_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = xl_app.Workbooks
```

is generating the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-ec4dea6cd4c3> in <module>
      4 xl_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
      5 
----> 6 wb = xl_app.Workbooks

~\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    525 
    526                 # no where else to look.
--> 527                 raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
    528 
    529         def __setattr__(self, attr, value):

AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks
```

This seems like there should be something really obvious that I'm missing but I can't figure it out. This is the VBA library reference which I have checked and can't find any spelling errors in my work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbooks

I am trying to run it in a Jupyter notebook. I have also tried saving it as a .py file and running it through Powershell and I get the same error message.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, try installing `openpyxl`  from [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and your life will be better in terms of handling `Excel` object... Start with `import openpyxl` and read something about it, on the same page where the link will bring you. Code examples, documentation etc.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to use the win32com library is that I'm working with a program (cognos) that generates corrupted .xls files. Can openpyxl read corrupted .xls files? Would certainly save me a lot of headache if it could. re the question, I think it has something to do with whether or not I have an instance of excel running in the background, but even then it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I can't seem to pin down a pattern and reliably reproduce the error.